# Duplicate images using GSCAM

Tags: ros, gscam, image-view, video, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use GSCAM to capture video from a composite video input through a ViewCast Osprey 230 analogue video capture card.

I have set *GSCAM_CONFIG* to:

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

And viewing the video through *image_view*

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_view
```

The problem is the image is duplicated. I only get this problem running when using *gscam* and the capture card, a USB webcam I have tested works fine. I presume that I need to alter *GSCAM_CONFIG* but I have not been able to find the correct configuration yet.

Screenshot of my problem: [Duplicate images http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ecclw05/v4l2-20110727.png](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ecclw05/v4l2-20110727.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10755/duplicate-images-using-gscam/) by [Charence](https://answers.ros.org/users/908/charence/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-03-26**:
when i give rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_view, i'm getting only empty window without video. how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some more searching, I believe I need to perform some kind of interlacing to alternate between the images from the top field and bottom field. Haven't figured out how to do that yet..

Meanwhile, I have resorted to cropping and resizing. I'm sure this is wrong, but I'm doing this until I figure out how to interlace the video.

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videocrop top=0 left=0 right=0 bottom=288 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=720,height=576 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

---

Originally posted by [Charence](https://answers.ros.org/users/908/charence/) with karma: 137 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Charence](https://answers.ros.org/users/908/charence/) on 2011-07-29**:
This page has some more info: http://www.100fps.com/